# Why is my onEdit script not copying cell to adjoining cell when edited?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I am trying to copy the cell value in column B to the next adjoining cell when its value is edited. The idea is that the value in the adjoining cell is also copied to the next adjoining cell when the column B cell is again edited, thus creating a registry of the values this cell has had. This is what I have done but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function copyProd(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSpreadSheet().getActiveSheet();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var inputValue = e.value;
if ((sheetName == "Cart") && (e.range.getColumn() == 2)) {
var row = e.range.getRow();
var ss_ans_val = spreadSheet.getRange(row,3,1,22).getValues();
ss.getRange(row,4,1,22).setValues(ss_ans_val);
ss.getRange(row,3,1,1).setValue(e.oldValue);
}
}
```

This is supposed to be triggered by an onEdit installable trigger which fails. I'm a noob and would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tBsZd3XcuZLwkvmDWM4obtQ46FA4RRoWVDVI5ae5uRE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if ((sh.getName() == "Cart") && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    //e.source.toast("Flag1")
    var ss_ans_val = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3, 1, 22).getValues();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4, 1, 22).setValues(ss_ans_val);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3).setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

If this is all you require then having an installable trigger is not required.

Comment: It's partially working but the second time the cell is edited, it's not copying to the adjacent cell, although the previous value that was copied does copy to the next adjacent cell. It seems to skip a column. Here's a screenshot: https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZg0ORVZuyhTOtDav2zUmzibWHz79BqtYxz7

Comment: I  tried it on your account and it seems to be working for me

Comment: @Cooper, I got rid of the trigger I had and it works fine now. Thank you! How could I publish it as a web app, if you don't mind me asking? I don't know how to do the doGet.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to publish it as a webapp

Comment: I would like to get a URL to use it in an external request in a bot.

Comment: Well the short answer is that you need to be using and doPost() or a doGet() and then you need to deploy it as a webapp using the blue button in the Script Editor.  Beyond that I can't help you because I don't really understand how it fits.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. You've been a load of help!